# Selenium Webdriver - Switch between several active simulteneus sessions in the same test

Tags: session, selenium, browser, webdriver

I came across scenarios where  I need to open several independent, different drivers browser sessions in the same run and move between them, i.e    NOT different windows opened by same driver via click on links, and NOT different tabs, popups of the same driver, and NOT testing of the same test on different browsers.

For Example: Test max number of allowed simultenous opened sessions by the same user and then move between sessions to gracefully logout and close.

I have researched web extensively and found only 1 reference not related to my tests.

After many experiments I have found a solution and now take a courage to share with the community the approach how to test such cases.  It is my first post an I hope it will help others.

Code below will open initial driver followed by 5 **other drivers** to perform successful active log-ins and then 6th login which generates an error.  After that there is a switch between different sessions/browsers to logout and close  all opened drivers/sessions.

```
               ArrayList<WebDriver> Drivers=new ArrayList<WebDriver>();                 

                String winHandleOnLoad=driver.getWindowHandle();
                for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){

                    WebDriver loopdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    Drivers.add(i,loopdriver);
                    loopdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    loopdriver.get("YOUR URL");

                    WebElement uname = loopdriver.findElement(By.name(loginNameID));
                    WebElement pwd = loopdriver.findElement(By.name(PasswordID));
                    if ((uname.isDisplayed()==false) ||pwd.isDisplayed()==false) {
                         bPass=false;
                         break;
                    }
                    else{
                         // set the user name and pwd  in input text box and submit to login   
                          uname.sendKeys(LoginName);
                          pwd.sendKeys(password);               
                          pwd.submit();
                     }            

                    if(i<5){
                        // Verify that user successfully logged in performed agaisnt (LoginName)published on a page
                        String title=loopdriver.findElement(By.xpath("yourVerificationID")).getText();
                        if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(LoginName)){
                            System.out.println("Found Title="+title);  // Verify login
                        }
                        else{
                            bPass=false;
                        }
                    }
                    else{  // 6th opened browser session should generate an error
                        String error=loopdriver.findElement(By.xpath("yourErrorLocationID")).getText();
                        if(error.contentEquals(Expected)){
                            System.out.println("True:Expected Error="+Expected+" Actual Error="+error);
                            bPass=true;
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Error Message is NOT Correct:Expected Error="+Expected+" Actual Error="+error);
                                     bPass=false;
                        }
                        loopdriver.close();
                    }   
                }

        //Switch between sessions to logout and close
                for(int j=0;j<=4;j++){

                    WebDriver getDriver=Drivers.get(j);
                    getDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();

                    getDriver.findElement(By.xpath("yourLogoutLinkID")).click();
                getDriver.close();                              
                }
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); //close initial "empty" window
                driver.quit();
                if (bPass==true){                       
                    System.out.println("PASSED");

                }else if (bPass==false){
                    System.out.println("FAILED");                       
                }

        }//END
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a question-answer site, see [ask] and [help]. Perhaps you might want to open a blog.

Comment: Are are asking a question If so what and where is it??????

Comment: Sorry, I had a question and could not found any answers to it. When I did come with an answer, I thought it would be good to share it. So, This is both question and an answer.  Sorry again,  if this is not a right place.

Comment: Then you should have asked this as a question and if none answered you can add your code as an answer.That'll be a proper way